# Load local docker images using docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy a DMS, but for backup reasons, I want the images not being fetched from any repo, but instead load them locally (in case the whole system fails in the future).
So I created a .tar file (`docker save -o`) from each downloaded image and put them each on a folder with its name, as you may see in the structure placed below.

After reading from different sources:

- A saved tar image can't be loaded directly using docker-compose.
- It has to be done with a dockerfile per tar file to be loaded.

So, I have this docke-compose.yml file that looks like this:

```
    version: "3.4"
    services:
      db:
    # image: docker.io/library/postgres:15
    build:
      context: ./images/postgres
      dockerfile: dockerfile
      args:
        - --no-cache
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /home/${USER}/paperless-ngx/paperless/dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
...
```

*It continues with other images needed for the DMS, it just changes on the context line to a different folder.*

And the dockerfile in each folder looks like:

```
FROM docker:latest
RUN docker load -i ./postgres.tar
```

However I just get the error:
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c docker load -i ./postgres.tar]: exit code: 1

At this point I'm quite lost, since I don't find how to properly load local tar files using docker-compose and another thing I'm trying to avoid is that the tar files have online dependencies.

The current structure is:

```
--Mainfolder
  --images
    --gotenberg
      --dockerfile
      --gotenberg.tar
    --tika
      --dockerfile
      --tika.tar
    --paperless
      --dockerfile
      --paperless-ngx.tar
    --postgres
      --dockerfile
      --postgres.tar
    --redis
      --dockerfile
      --redis.tar
  --paperless
  --docker-compose.env
  --docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to keep the images as fiels? The easiest solution would be to justo load the images in your docker host (the machine you run the docker commands from) and then in the compose file just specify `pull_policy: never`

Comment: Could you please develop better your possible answer? 
What I'm trying to accomplish is that the docker-compose.yml is in charge of everything. 
Where should I put pull_policy?

Comment: `pull_policy` is a configuration option for services in docker-compose (take a look at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#pull_policy). My suggestion, though, is only valid if you can store all the images in the docker context (not as files...)

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to use a `docker save` tar file is to `docker load` it on the target system before `docker run` (or `docker-compose up`) containers from it.  Since loading the tar file will cause the images to exist locally, Docker won't try to pull them from the registry.

That is:

```sh
# locally: save every image mentioned in the Compose file
docker compose images --format json \
  | jq -r 'map(.Repository + ":" + .Tag) | join("\n")' \
  | xargs docker save -o images.tar
gzip images.tar
cp images.tar.gz docker-compose.yml /mnt
```

```sh
# remotely:
gunzip images.tar.gz
docker load -i images.tar
docker-compose up -d
```

This also means you do not need to try to write a Dockerfile that just loads a preëxisting image from somewhere else.  (In general you cannot run `docker` commands from within a Dockerfile at all, even in an image `FROM docker` or `FROM docker:dind`.)  The Compose file should list the actual images you're using.  Saving and reloading it will preserve its name and tag.

Also consider whether backing up and restoring the registry is more productive for you.  Your application probably has a combination of standard Docker Hub images and locally-built images, and you may not need to back up anything at all: it's probably safe to depend on Docker Hub (though your needs and requirements may vary, and nothing is truly 100% available) and you can rebuild your local images from source, so losing the local registry entirely may not be that dangerous for you.